# Make Cell Clickable In UIViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, cell, viewcontroller

I am using a UIViewController and a Table View/Table View Cell (extending to delegate/datasource). Whenever a cell is clicked from MessageController, it is supposed to be directed into another View Controller, called ChatController. Even though I am using didSelectRowAt and adding a segue with identifier, it does not switch to the ChatController.

```
import UIKit

class MessagesController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var myIndex = 0;
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var tableData: [MModel] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.dataSource = self

    MData.getData { (data) in
        self.tableData = data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageCell") as! MessagesCell
    cell.setup(model: tableData[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 375

}
//clicking on cell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
}


}
```

The problematic line is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set the delegate to the tableview.

Set it as:
after`tableView.dataSource = self`

`tableView.delegate = self`

Answer (score 1):

You must set the delegate also in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

my problem had to do with having a GestureRecognizer in my viewDidLoad(). after so many hours of troubleshooting i realize that what was breaking the code was that 'hide keyboard' code of GestureRecognizer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).